# How to set custom theme attribute programmatically in Android 10

Tags: java, android, themes

It is easy to change theme attributes in styles.xml, and to define new custom theme attributes in attrs.xml.

**But how to do it in java code?**

After calling setTheme in Activity, how to change or define attribute programmatically?

**TestActivity.java**

> ```
> @Override
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>
>     // Apply "AppTheme" to this Activity
>     super.setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
>
>     // How to change theme attribute "colorPrimary" or "android.R.attr.colorPrimary" in here?
>
>     // How to define new custom theme attribute "customThemeAttribute" in here?
> }
> ```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some research, there is no way to set theme attribute programmatically.

Comment: Well, I am glad you researched. This might go out of scope of OP's question, but I think it doesn't. But isn't there alternatives? I recently started to segregate/extract repeated attributes from my XML view files into `<style>` elements. I followed [this guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes) . This removes duplication, that's fine... So, now I got a main `MyStyle` that I apply to the main layouts, and several children for other color settings. Isn't it possible to apply those `<style>`s to the implied objects programatically?